# Can boolean logic compute any sort of mathematical operation?

Tags: propositional-calculus, foundations

Computers fundamentally do logical operations on the input and memory they have (as far as I know). Computers are used by mathematicians to do all sorts of mathsy operations (as far as I know). Does this mean then that you could use Boolean logic to do any mathematical operation?

If yes, does not this suggest that logic is the basic underpinning of mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

Everything eventually boils down to a simple true or false. Look at the way computers work, binary is a perfect example of boolean logic at its finest. You then have logical statements that act as decision gates for operations. There are used almost everywhere if you dig deep into the workings of a system or process.